# Regex - Can't get specific attributes from a HTML element

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have the following HTML elements:

```
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/share"></iframe>


<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.google.com/share"></iframe>


<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.yahoo.com/share"></iframe>
```

I ant to use Regex in order to find the `iframe` with a specific `src` `(has to contain https://www.stackoverflow.com/share/{s}` attribute and get the other attributes associated within this html attribute.

So in this instance, the regex would return:

`Group 1: https://www.google.com/share
Group 2: 100
Group 3: 200`

I have tried the following:

`iframe.*src[^""]+['"]+(https:\/\/www.google.com\/share)`

Which finds the specific URL and gives me it the group, no matter where it is within the string.

The issue I'm facing is expanding on this to return all of the other attributes within the HTML element.

I have tried the add the following to the Regex:

`\s+width="(.*?)"\s+height="(.*?)"`

But this returns no match.

How (possibly), using the current regex that I've formed to get the remaining attributes values using regex?

[My regex 101 file](https://regex101.com/r/YiYXDg/1)

Comment: Regex is not the best choice for parsing HTML. Use a real parser instead, for ecample HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @FlatEric Hey - I have to use regex for this specific project!

Comment: [It is too bad you must use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Do you have `\K` suppport? You can use `iframe.*src[^""]+['"]+\K(https:\/\/www.google.com\/share)` https://regex101.com/r/YiYXDg/2

Comment: @mrzasa Finding the `src` is fine, I have achieived that. It's finding the other elements such as `width` and `height` that is the problem i'm facing

Comment: width and height in your sample code are in the opposite order than in your regex. Apart from that: I also recommend to use HtmlAgilityPack. In order for your regex to work reliably with all valid HTMLs, you had to support different attribute ordering, HTML comments, whitespace etc.A HTML parser takes care of all that for you.

Comment: Isn't [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) better than HtmlAgilityPack? Why does everyone still recommend HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Yeah I cannot use anything but regex so do you think it will be impossible to do it using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

For URLs like `http://stackoverflow.com/share/xxx` use (see https://regex101.com/r/bKbfTt/6):

`iframe\s*(?:\s|width="(.*?)"|height="(.*?)")+src="(.*?www\.stackoverflow\.com\/share\/.*?)"`

For URLs like `http://stackoverflow.com/share` (without the `/xxx` part) use (see https://regex101.com/r/bKbfTt/5):

`iframe\s*(?:\s|width="(.*?)"|height="(.*?)")+src="(.*?www\.stackoverflow\.com\/share(?:\/.*?)?)"`

The tested cases are:

```
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/share/xxx"></iframe>

<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/share/xxx"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/share"></iframe>

<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.google.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.google.com/share/xxx"></iframe>

<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.yahoo.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.yahoo.com/share/xxx"></iframe>
```

**Previous answer**

Check this out: https://regex101.com/r/bKbfTt/1

The regex is `iframe\s*(?:\s|width="(.*?)"|height="(.*?)"|src="(.*?)")+` which matched your examples:

```
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.google.com/share"></iframe>
<iframe height="100" width="200" src="https://www.yahoo.com/share"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way to match a specific URL? It cannot be applied to all i frames on the the page only ones with a specific URL

Comment: I updated the file: https://regex101.com/r/bKbfTt/2 Is this what you want? I'm still not really sure. ;-)

Comment: it shows there are 4 results when there should only be one since it should only match the one where the url matches.. if that makes sense? So if the URL is stackoverflow.com/share it would only match that one and give me the attributes for that case

Comment: Well, the problem is that width, height and src could be in any order. Or is the order fixed? Or is src always the last attribute?

Comment: Is it possible to check the string in multiple steps? Like 1. Check if it is an iframe, 2. check for `src="(.*?www\.stackoverflow\.com\/share\/.*?)"`, 3. check for `width="(.*?)"`, 4. check for `height="(.*?)")`

Comment: Yeah this is fine to check because I just want to isolate that an iframe with the specific URL exists and get the attributes. I believe the positioning of the elements will not change

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use your solution to figure it out and now it works just fine! Going to do some more testing but accepting your answer :)